# How to multiply columns of same names belonging to different data.frame

Tags: r

I am having a problem... I have two data. frames with a lot of columns and these two data.frames are of different length, in fact one has many rows and second data.frame has only one row.... But in both data frames there are columns of same names. Now, I want to multiply the matching columns with each other. I fail to solve it. Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command

```
mapply("*", DataFrame1, DataFrame2)
```

should work if you want to multiply all columns. If the relevant columns are only a subset of all columns in the data frames, we first need to identify the columns being present in both data frames.

```
mapply("*", DataFrame1[intersect(names(DataFrame1), names(DataFrame2))],
       DataFrame2[intersect(names(DataFrame1), names(DataFrame2))])
```

Comment: I believe this approach will work for any pair of dataframes, as R will repeat the shorter (fewer rows) one as needed to match the longer.

Comment: Sven Hohenstein thanks for the reply... I just want to ask one more question related to this, can I use the row names of one data.frame in the same manner. e.g. mapply("*",DataFrame1[intersect(row.names(DataFrame1),names(DataFrame2))],DataFrame2[intersect(row.names(DataFrame1),names(DataFrame2))])
Best regards
Maria

Comment: @maria riaz This command should work: `mapply("*", as.data.frame(t(DataFrame1))[intersect(rownames(DataFrame1), names(DataFrame2))], DataFrame2[intersect(rownames(DataFrame1), names(DataFrame2))])`. By this command, the rows of `DataFrame1` are multiplied with the corresponding columns (here: single values) of `DataFrame2`.

Comment: @Sven Hohenstein... I tried this code but the ouput is 'named list ()'
I have two data frame with many columns. I want to multiply all the columns that are with common names in these two data frame. some of the columns that are not common will be left out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @mariariaz What are the results of `str(DataFrame1)` and `str(DataFrame2)`?

Comment: @SvenHohenstein just to add one thing, I tried it once again and now all the values are 'NA', whereas I was expecting the multiplied values.

Comment: @SvenHohenstein for DataFrame 2 it is: dataFrame: 1 obs of 211 Variables and that is num
for DataFrame1 it is int for all the columns that I needed.

Comment: @SvenHohenstein Thank you very much it worked.... I don't know the code was giving NAs but than it give me the right output... Thanks once again

Comment: @SvenHohenstein sorry to disturb you but I just realized that the code you suggested me have some problems as it is working but it is mixing the values and giving me wrong results. could you look into it. As, I have big data set so now when I was double checking I realized the mistake. Thanks.

Comment: @mariariaz Please clarify "mixing the values and giving me wrong results".

Comment: well it was some bug as it was rearranging the rownames. Just to confirm I did the analysis on second computer and it worked well. Now, I re-installed it. That is bit scary as now I have to check all the analysis manually. Sorry for the wrong alarm. Thanks for your help.