# Multiply only columns with same names

Tags: r

I have a dataset as follows:

```
df1

Col1   Col2    A    B    C
   A      1    2    3    4
   B      2    5    7    8

df2

A    B     C   D    E
2    3     4   7   10
```

I want to multiply only the columns that are matching in both dataframes.

Final expected output:

```
Col1   Col2     A    B     C
   A      1     4    9    16
   B      2    10   21    32
```

My dataframe has many columns so if this could be dynamic in any way then it would be super helpful.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please include any code (erring or just incorrect).

Comment: Do df1 and df2 have the same number of rows/do you only have one df2 row?

Comment: I only have 1 row for df2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to multiply columns of same names belonging to different data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12554879/how-to-multiply-columns-of-same-names-belonging-to-different-data-frame)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
df1[] <- mapply(function(nm, dat) if (nm %in% names(df2) && is.numeric(dat)) dat*df2[[nm]] else dat,
                names(df1), df1, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
df1
#   Col1 Col2  A  B  C
# 1    A    1  4  9 16
# 2    B    2 10 21 32
```

The `df1[] <- ...` is effectively (though not precisely) a shortcut of `df1 <- as.data.frame(...)`.

I was just about to suggest `intersect` when Julius' answer came up ... but I'll include it for completeness (since the rest of that answer is a little different anyway):

```
df1[intersect(names(df1), names(df2))] <- 
  mapply(function(nm, dat) dat*df2[[nm]],
         intersect(names(df1), names(df2)), df1[intersect(names(df1), names(df2))], SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
nm <- intersect(names(df1), names(df2))
df1[nm] <- sweep(df1[nm], 2, unlist(df2[nm]), `*`)
df1
#   Col1 Col2  A  B  C
# 1    A    1  4  9 16
# 2    B    2 10 21 32
```

Using `sweep` is the main trick here.